# How to create table for a generalized class diagram?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, class-diagram

I am developing a online job portal website. In class diagram I generalized Employer & Employee as Members class & I put 'MID' as primary key. Now I am confused how to create tables for Employer & Employee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is tables you required:

```
Member
========
Id (or MId) (PK)
... (Specifications you need)

Employer
========
Id (PK)
MId (FK to Member table)
... (Specifications you need)

Employee
========
Id (PK)
MId (FK to Member table)
EId (FK to Employer table)
... (Specifications you need)
```